# binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for xxx ms

Tags: android, multithreading, android-source, android-8.0-oreo, android-os-handler

Our Android service is using a HIDL service to interact with our driver/hw but during long-runs we are seeing lot of these prints "binder thread pool (1 threads) starved for xxx ms" with 120ms < xxx > 310ms. And after sometime we are seeing the memory copied from HIDL service is fault address and when we access it gives SIGSEGV. Is the thread pool starving and memory getting corrupted related ? Has anyone seen a similar issue ? This is with Android O preview.

Comment: Same here with android_8.0.0-r34. Did you compile the kernel too?